# Problemas con manejos de ficheros PYTHON

Tags: python, archivo, io

estoy tratando de realizar un código de prueba para trabajar con ficheros en Visual Code, realizo todo el tema de la importación del paquete io y el modulo open, pero de solo colocar la linea from io import open ya me muestra error, me dice "Expected module name Pylance" y "Expected import Pylance", pensé que era problema de visual code así que reinicie el programa, es decir empecé desde 0, y me reconoció la importación del modulo, sin embargo al trabajar con open, no me crea archivos ni tampoco lee los que cree aparte con el block de notas

```
from io import open

archivoPlano = open("ArchivoPrueba.txt", "w")
```

Debería crear el archivo con esta instrucción pero no lo esta haciendo

Comment: Intenta desactivando la extensión Pylance.

Comment: No importes nada, la funcion `open()` es nativa de python, no necesitas ningún módulo extra

Comment: Acabo de confirmar varias cosas y luego de la ultima actualizacion de visual studio code hay un bug que no esta dejando funcionar el paquete de io

Comment: @WillDiaz no!, la funcion `open()` no depende de ningun modulo, quita ese modulo de tu código y funcionará

Comment: Probe lo que me comentas pero aun asi esta ocasionando un fallo, si utilizo open() para crear el archivo, no lo crea. y si lo utilizo en modo de lectura no lee los archivos de texto que tengo, me dice que no existe el archivo en el directorio, no se si debo darle algun permiso a VS Code o que estara pasando pero no me funciona con ese IDE, probe con otros y funciona normalmente, debe ser un bug en el IDE

Comment: @WillDiaz Para crear un archivo tienes que hacerlo así `open("archivo.txt","w")`